# Python List of Strings to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to take a list in python and execute it in MySQL:

```
list = ['tom', 'larry', 'moe']

select * from test.db where name in (list).
```

I have tried to `",".join` the list but it doesn't seem to work.

What is the correct way I can pass a list into MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you'd want to do something like:

```
subs = ','.join('%s' for _ in lst)
sql = "select * from test.db where name in ({})".format(subs)
cursor.execute(sql, tuple(subs))
```